# How to find a substring index in a string with different line ending in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, string, substring, line-endings

I have two strings

> 1. abc`\r\n`def
> 2. c`\n`de

And I need to find index of string 2 inside string 1.

I can't obviously use `indexOf()`, so I need something that would work like it, but took different line endings into consideration.

I cannot modify the original string because I need substring index in the original string. If I replace all `\r\n` with `\n` it will mess up original indexes, so I would have to restore them somehow.

Comment: What should be the output?

Comment: The output should be "2" (0-based index of string c\nde inside abc\r\ndef)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(FWIW, there's nothing TypeScript-specific about this question. Just JavaScript.)

You can do it by converting the string you're looking for into a regular expression using the alternation `\r\n|\r|\n` everywhere it has any of those sequences, and being sure to escape the parts in-between (see [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) for that). When you use the `exec` method of the resulting regular expression on the first string, if it matches, the return value (let's call it `match`) will be a match result (enhanced array) with the index available as `match.index` and the matched text available as `match[0]`.

Example with TypeScript type annotations commented out:

```js
// From https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/157247
function escapeRegex(string) {
    return string.replace(/[/\-\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
}

function test(str/*: string */, substr/*: string*/) {
    // Split up the text on any of the newline sequences,
    // then escape the parts in-between,
    // then join together with the alternation
    const rexText = substr
        .split(/\r\n|\n|\r/)
        .map((part) => escapeRegex(part))
        .join("\\r\\n|\\n|\\r");
    // Create the regex
    const re = new RegExp(rexText);
    // Run it
    const match = re.exec(str);
    if (match) {
        console.log(`Found ${JSON.stringify(match[0])} at index ${match.index} in ${JSON.stringify(str)}`);
    } else {
        console.log(`Not found`);
    }
}


test("abc\r\ndef", "c\nde");
```

Comment: `.join("(?:\\r\\n|\\n|\\r)")` you need to group these or the `|` will mess up your regex